# Why does a TPMS alert go off after replacing tires?

Tags: wheels, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have a 2015 Honda CRV.  I just got my tires replaced.  After driving a few miles, the TPMS alert goes off and keeps going off even after I've reset the alert.  I've checked my tires several times along my trip home and also after I let the tires cool down.  The pressure is at the recommended level (33 psi).

I went back to complain to Costco the next day that they broke or installed something wrong but they said they weren't mechanics and that the TPMS system on my car was not an air sensor in the tire but one that checked while braking what was happening to the wheel.

I called his bluff because I know the TPMS alert went off while I was at a stop light.  I was stopped behind several cars at the light so I reset it and it went off 2 minutes later before I STARTED MOVING so no braking was involved.  He still went back to telling me to go to the dealership or mechanic to look at the TPMS system.

So back to my original question: why would a TPMS alert go off after replacing tires?

- Is it because the tires are new and the computer inside the car needs to recalibrate to the spinning of the new tires?
- Did Costco break something and are just making things up hoping I won't use my head to figure out they are lying to get out of liability?
- Was the sensor on its last legs and just coincidentally broke at the same time the tires were replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model year uses indirect pressure monitoring. It uses the tone ring and speed sensors to trigger the alarm. The owners manual suggests that it be recalibrated after tire rotation, tire repair or tire change.

Comment: I think it could be either method of monitoring, as I see parts offered for both.

Comment: Yes, it appears that true TPMS was an optional item.  So it could be either one.

Comment: @Paulster2 you may be right. I got my info from following site. The OP might look at this and find it very helpful. https://www.ateq-tpms.com/en-us/article/tpms-diagnostic-information-honda-cr-v/

Comment: I would assume that if you have the TPMS reset feature that you have a passive system.  Did you drive for 10 minutes without stopping after resetting the system?  The $3 charge was likely a fee to change "O" rings on the valve stems if applicable.

Comment: @Jupiter, thx for the link.  There was a video in there that said I needed to start the calibration and drive for 30 min at speeds between 30-60mph.  I guess it started and ended calibration by itself b/c the TPMS warning went off after driving around running errands.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no doubt in my mind that the TPMS module was damaged during the tire change and no longer works as it should.  Generally they should have a "rebuild" kit for the sensor which includes a new battery and seal but this is not the case at all tire retailers.  But it's definitely something you should have addressed with them in advance.

> TPMS system on my car was not an air sensor in the tire but one that
> checked while braking what was happening to the wheel.

There are some vehicles that use the ABS ring on the wheels to determine if a tire is lower than the others because as it deflates the tire will rotate faster than the non-deflated ones.  But these don't show the tire pressure.

It's possible that's what you car has.

Comment: Just to be clear, TPMS rebuild kits cost money. A tire retailer, while most likely having them, will not (in most cases) rebuild your sensor(s) for free.

Comment: Yeah, they charged like $3 each for some TPMS module thing.  Now that I think about it, maybe one of those $3 kits were a lemon and the fault doesn't entirely lie with Costco.  And yes, what you said about the ABS ring sounds like what he was telling me but I'm still mad that I called his bluff and he still didn't accept responsibility.

Comment: If they charged you $3 each then they presumably did some service on them.  I'd expect it to work.

Comment: If they charged you for the kit then they would *know* that the car does not have the passive (abs ring) system.